# How To redirect a website when accessed through its IP to its domain name - CentOS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, centos

I look after a CentOS server that used to host a couple of different websites.

Nowadays it's just one, but the apache configuration remains the same.

Everything works fine, but now I would like to, whenever I type the server IP address, be redirected to the domain name.

What is happening at the moment is that the server loads as expected, however the IP address remains in the browser, instead of the domain name.

I've tried mod_rewrite, but I don't think it's the case here. Anyway, it didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want to do this in the server config as a virtual host, or the default virtual host. But in htaccess, you just need to add this near the top of the file (before any other rewrite rules):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.4$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

where the 1.2.3.4 is your IP and example.com is your domain.

Comment: Hey @JonLin, amazing! I've tried that but not on top of the file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can place this rule as your very first rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```